# Windows Explorer Folder Options w Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, explorer

We are running Active directory on Windows Server 2008 R2.  All servers and desktops are Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2.

Is it possible to create a policy using GPO such that every account in an OU will have a certain set of Folder Option settings (Windows Explorer) set automatically and consistently whenever users in the OU log into any computer on the domain?

Basically, I want "Show Hidden files, folder and drives" enabled, fire extensions and hidden files visible on all machines automatically on all machines and **we want to achieve this without using roaming profiles**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, figured it out myself:

Its under User Configuration\Preferences\Control Panel Settings\Folder Options

Make sure you enforce the policy.  Also, it does not take effect until and unless you log out and log back in (after doing gpupdate /force of course...)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be looking under GPO>User Configuration>Preferences>Control Panel Settings>Folder Options. Once there right click on the Folder Options menu and Click New Folder options.